# Trying to rotate div on button click, but only works every 2nd click (using Javascript)

Tags: javascript

Hoping for help in getting this javascript I found online to work.  I am wanting to make the boxes rotate each time the button clicks. Currently it only rotates every second click.

```
<style>
.rotate {
    animation-name: example;
    animation-duration: 1s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes example {
    from { transform: rotateZ(0deg);}
    to { transform: rotateZ(360deg);}
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
function rotateBox(){
    var rotated = false;
    var div = document.getElementById('box'),
        deg = rotated ? 0 : 66;
    document.getElementById('box').classList.toggle('rotate');
    rotated = !rotated;
}       
</script>


<body>
    <div id="box" class="boxes" ></div> 
    <button class="button" onclick=" rotateBox()" >Rotate</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will add the "rotate" class when clicked, and set a timeout to remove the class after the animation has finished.

```js
function rotateBox() {
    document.getElementById('box').classList.add('rotate');
    window.setTimeout(function() {document.getElementById('box').classList.remove('rotate');}, 1000);
}
```

```css
div {
    width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid red;
}
.rotate {
    animation-name: example;
    animation-duration: 1s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes example {
    from { transform: rotateZ(0deg);}
    to { transform: rotateZ(360deg);}
}
```

```html
    <div id="box" class="boxes"></div> 
    <button class="button" onclick="rotateBox()">Rotate</button>
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. Even running the code snippet on this page, it only rotates once on the first button click, then nothing on subsequent clicks.  Appreciate your assistance though.

Comment: @adhoc I figured out the problem; this improved version works in Chrome (and probably all browsers that understand css animation).

Comment: Excellent, solved thanks.  I thought it was a problem with the toggle, but wasn't sure what to put instead.  You've ended quite a few hours of research for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `rotated` to be outside of the function:

```
var rotated = false;

function rotateBox(){
    var div = document.getElementById('box'),
        deg = rotated ? 0 : 66;

    document.getElementById('box').classList.toggle('rotate');
    rotated = !rotated;
}
```

Comment: As it is, the rotate and deg variables aren't doing anything.

Comment: Moving the rotated variable outside the function didn't make a difference for me.  If I delete the deg variable, it doesn't work at all.  If you're referring to not needing the rotated variable, I can do away with the 2nd reference, but not the first one.  The only other code I have is general CSS formatting for the div, button and body. Tried to paste it all  in the original question above, but it said I had too much code and not enough comment.